# Remove useless zero digits from decimals and remove decimals above 2 in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to find a fast way to first make my number 2 decimals only and then remove zero decimals from result values like this:

```
echo function(0.00);
// 0

echo function(125.70);
// 125.7

echo function(245.051);
// 245.05

echo function(2245.0090);
// 2245.01
```

I tried number format but when I call it with 0 it acts like this:

```
echo number_format(0,2)
// 0.00
```

But I want 0

Does there exist some optimized way to do that?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Comment: round returns 0.0 but i want 0

Comment: _“round returns 0.0”_ - what are you talking about? https://3v4l.org/62XVA

Comment: `round($number, 2)` gives exactly the results you were asking for, for all four test cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is `round()`.

```php
round(0.00, 2);           // float(0)
round(0.01, 2);           // float(0.01)
round(0.10, 2);           // float(0.1)
round(1.00, 2);           // float(1)
round(2245.0090, 2);      // float(2245.01)
round(1000.00, 2);        // float(1000)
```

Live demo at https://3v4l.org/IiimT.

Comment: ```echo myFormat(2245.0090); // 2245.0090``` but i want ```2245.01``` if it was more than 2 decimals as i show in question

Comment: Could you `round()` it first, then do as @Qirel suggests?

Comment: If you also want to round it, then just apply the `round()` function with a precision of 2. You can do that in the first line in the function. See the revised answer.

Comment: `round($number, 2);` alone already gives the exact same results for all the test cases mentioned here.

Comment: @Qirel what PHP version gives you a `0.0` for that? https://3v4l.org/s42P6

Comment: `round` _can not_ return `0.0`, because it returns an actual float - and those do not have trailing zeros after the decimal point in PHP. (`echo 0.0;` also only gets you `0`.) If you get `0.0` anywhere, then the value must have been sent through additional formatting at some place.

Comment: This answer is giving horrible advice! I am very surprised, @Qirel.  https://3v4l.org/N8jD5  `1000.00` becomes `1`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

```
<?php 
echo (float)number_format(0,2);
```